# How can I store a password in my Qt application?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qsettings, qt5.5

How can I store a password in my Qt application?

Is there no ready to use library by Qt ?

Currently I store all my application configurations by means of [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html).

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at https://github.com/frankosterfeld/qtkeychain/ . It works on Mac, Windows, Linux and has an example in the source code (see testclient.cpp).

From it's readme.md:

> QtKeychain QtKeychain is a Qt API to store passwords and other secret data securely. How the data is stored depends on the platform:
>
> - macOS: Passwords are stored in the macOS Keychain.
> - Linux/Unix: If running, GNOME Keyring is used, otherwise QtKeychain tries to use KWallet (via D-Bus), if available. Libsecret (common API
>   for desktop-specific solutions) is also supported.
> - Windows: By default, the Windows Credential Store is used (requires Windows 7 or newer). Pass -DUSE_CREDENTIAL_STORE=OFF to cmake to
>   disable it. If disabled, QtKeychain uses the Windows API function
>   CryptProtectData to encrypt the password with the user's logon
>   credentials. The encrypted data is then persisted via QSettings.
> - Android and iOS: Passwords are stored in the Android keystore system and iOS keychain, respectively.
>
> In unsupported environments QtKeychain will report an error. It will
> not store any data unencrypted unless explicitly requested.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need just authorize member use [`QCryptographicHash`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcryptographichash.html) class. Another case, for example to create connection with database, you need to encrypt your password.

One of possible way is [`SimpleCrypt`](https://wiki.qt.io/Simple_encryption_with_SimpleCrypt) library. Project has good docs and examples of usage.

Answer (score -2):

If you care security, you should not store your passwords. However you can use MD5 and HASH for encryption then put your result to QSettings.

Here is example result(Hex format) for QSettings;

```
QString result = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(("GoGuD"),QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());
```

Comment: Storing unsalted password hashes leaves the doors wide open for a rainbow table attack. Please add a salt to the hashed value.

Comment: As @demonplus said what are his security requirement? Of course he can also use $salt+$pepper, hashing to MAC is also possible.

Comment: how I should encrypt md5 hash in case I store password to third party service?)

Answer (score -3):

Well, so you want to encrypt your password in some way. The problem then is that you need a password to decrypt your password :|

What you can do if you're on linux with gnome (eg. ubuntu) is to use the [gnome-keyring](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-keyring/stable/ch01.html). Or another keyring service. This way, you unlock your system-wide keyring at login, with a master password, and it stores all your saved passwords. At least, of applications that support it.
On windows/mac there might be a built in keyring that you could use, but i have no experience with that.

Comment: The wonderful thing about passwords is that it's nobody's business to know what they really are - apart from the person who uses the password, that is. You don't need to store actual passwords, encrypted or not. You want to store something that can be used to verify that the password is correct. That's known as a hash of the password. It avoids any need to store the password itself. Hashes are one-way functions: it is impossible to know what the password was by looking at its hash only. You can try various passwords and see if they hash to the same thing, of course, but there's many that will.

Comment: Well, yes, but this does require that whatever service that you are authenticating to accepts a hash and not a password. But you are right, most services require a hash these days.

Comment: I think the confusion here is whether the the question is about verifying a password to use the application, or about saving a password for some remote api.